# Cannot change UINavigationBar color (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I have tried what seems like every possible combination to change the NavBar color for my application to an RGB value.

The only thing that works is the following:

```
listViewNavBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Since I want to use a custom RGB color I did the following:

```
var navBarColor = UIColor()
navBarColor = UIColor(red: 231, green: 76, blue: 60, alpha: 1)
```

However, when I run this I get a totally white navbar

Please recommend some other solutions that could work. I think there may be an issue with not importing some sort of Delegate?

Comment: If you option click on a method, it will bring up the documentation, which reveals that these particular parameters are specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: This worked well. Thank you!

Comment: are you using cells?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with the `UINavigationBar`:

```
navBarColor = UIColor(red: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
```

Parameters for `UIColor` are *float*, not *int*:

```
UIColor(colorLiteralRed: Float, green: Float, blue: Float, alpha: Float)
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the background color of a navigation bar, set the
`barTintColor` property to a color:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 242.0/255.0, green:
116.0/255.0, blue: 119.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```